# Stream.Position throws DisposedObjectException, what to check for?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a ExceptionFilter where I read the content from the request;

```
        using (var stream = await _actionExecutedContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            try
            {
                stream.Position = 0;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException exception)
            {
                return $"Stream in RequestContentAsync is unreadable. {exception}";
            }

        }
```

Suddenly this starts to throw the exception while I try to reset the stream position.

I am a little puzzled by this, and wonder if I should "just" copy the stream or if I should be aware of something else.

I don't read from the stream elsewhere.

```
"exceptionMessage": "Cannot access a disposed object.",
  "exceptionType": "System.ObjectDisposedException",
  "stackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.SeekableBufferedRequestStream.set_Position(Int64 value)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.DelegatingStream.set_Position(Int64 value)\r\n
```

Update 2:

Full code of exception filter:

```
    public override async Task OnExceptionAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //helper for request specific data
        var requestContentReader = new RequestContentReader(actionExecutedContext);

        //build up error log message 
        var logMessage = "REQUEST CONTENT: ";
            logMessage += Environment.NewLine;
            logMessage += await requestContentReader.RequestContentAsync();
            logMessage += Environment.NewLine;
            logMessage += "REQUEST URI: ";
            logMessage += actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.RequestContext.Url.Request.RequestUri.ToString();

        //Log error to database
        var logId = API.Logging.Logger.Log(logMessage, actionExecutedContext.Exception);

        //Create response to client and display requestid
        actionExecutedContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent($"An error occured in the application, your Error identifier is {logId}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"),
            StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
        };

        #if DEBUG
            throw actionExecutedContext.Exception;
        #endif
    }
}
```

Comment: Try it without the async/await.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to copy the stream. It should do the trick;

```
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await _actionExecutedContext.Request.Content.CopyToAsync(ms);
            try
            {
                ms.Position = 0;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms))
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException exception)
            {
                return $"Stream in RequestContentAsync is unreadable. {exception}";
            }

        }
```